# Angular JS Does Not Show Result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular JS and I tried to see how databinding works in Angular so I coded this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Tutorials</title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script5.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.firstName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.lastName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.gender"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem whenever I load the page it does not work at all!

And this is the `script5.js`:

```
var myApp = angular
            .module("myModule",[]);
            .controller("myController",function($scope){
                var employee = {
                    firstName: "Ben",
                    lastName: "Hastings",
                    gender: "Male"
                };
                $scope.employee = employee;
            });
```

However I have included the required file which is `angular.min.js` in the same directory as well.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: You are using two instances of `ng-app`

Answer (score 2):

Change

From

```
<html ng-app>
```

To

```
<html>
```

AND CONTROLLER AS

```
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
                var employee = {
                    firstName: "Ben",
                    lastName: "Hastings",
                    gender: "Male"
                };
                $scope.employee = employee;
            });
```

since you are declaring the module inside the body.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
                var employee = {
                    firstName: "Ben",
                    lastName: "Hastings",
                    gender: "Male"
                };
                $scope.employee = employee;
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Tutorials</title>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.firstName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.lastName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="employee.gender"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are declare ng-app beside the html declaration,and also in body.your angular instance is loaded in head so it applicable for body section so,remove ng-app at top,after code will works.